# Why does a previously deleted migration keep returning on creating a model in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

For a fresh start,

I've deleted all my migration files, dropped all tables in MySQL and deleted all the table migrations columns in MySQL.

But when i'm running `php artisan make:model Article`  Laravel responds by

```
Model created successfully.
Created Migration: 2015_04_28_181243_create_articles_table
```

Which is a migration file i've deleted previously! Why does it keep returning this way? and how can i get rid of it completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the `make:model` command generates a migration by default.
To opt-out of this add the `no-migration` option:

```
php artisan make:model Article --no-migration
```